# Erase configured static ip route on gcp VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, instance, ubuntu-18.04

I visualize that my static route are getting wipes off from my /etc/netplan file as soon as the network deamon service is restarted on GCE VM having Ubuntu 18.04

As a workaround :

1) I have already added startup script to add routes when GCE VM restarts ( no issues with that if vm restarts )

2) I have also added cron job running inside vm for checking every 1 min and  adding routes when erased.

But I am looking for some permanent solution of static routes not getting erased at all  when the network deamon service is restarted. I know its rear for network service to restarts but when it does then its very much affects my production environment causung tons of money loss.

Comment: maybe you should check why network(or service) is restarting too often

Comment: As the VM is on gcp project and its on in our hands to know when it will cause it restarts as if any upgrades of python or any other might cause this , do you have any idea on how to check its health

Comment: Use this as a reference https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs#checking_whether_instances_are_healthy . Although this is in managed instance groups the concept is still applicable

Comment: I dont think you understand my scenario, I am saying the network deamon service running on OS level when that gets restarts it causing my routes to wipes out from my netplan file, and the one you send checks the hardware health check

Comment: Have you tried setting the route in the interfaces file -etc/network/interfaces. You can check out this [link] (https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/add-permanent-static-route-ubuntu/) and it will give you instructions on how to use the interfaces file to add static routes permanently